# How to preserve component instances in Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I have a similar component and I whish to save the instance of the `InnerComponent` the first time it is rendered and render the same instance every time without reinstanceiating it.

```
@if(isVisible)
{
    <InnerComponent @ref="@_InnerComponent" @key="@("InnerComponentKey")">
        @ChildContent
    </InnerComponent>
}

@code{
    [Parameter] public InnerComponent _InnerComponent { get; set; }
    private bool IsVisible { get; set; }
}
```

When the inner component is visible the user can manipulate its state.
But if `IsVisible` gets set to false and then true again, the inner component gets rerendered overriding `_InnerComponent` and thus we lose track of the changes that the user made to that `InnerComponent` instance.

Adding @key does not seem to help preserve the instance either. It just gets rerendered and overwritten :/ I am sure, that I am feeding it the same key both times it gets rendered, but I don't know how to inspect the keys that it gets compared to.

If it is possible to render a component instance I could do something like the following, but I can't seem to find a way to do that.

```
@if(isVisible)
{
    @if(_InnerComponent == null)
    {
        <InnerComponent @ref="@_InnerComponent" @key="@("InnerComponentKey")">
            @ChildContent
        </InnerComponent>
    }
    else
    {
        @_InnerComponent.Render()
    }
}
```

I am taking criticism on my question since I haven't asked many :)

Thanks in advance!

#### Simplified example:

Let's say we have the following component that I am going to call `CounterContainer` , where `<Counter>` is the counter component from the default Blazor project template.

```
@if(CounterIsVisible)
{
    <Counter @ref="@_Counter" @key="@("CounterKey")" />
}

<button @onclick="() => CounterIsVisible = !CounterIsVisible">
    Show/Hide counter 
</button>

@code{
    [Parameter] public Counter _Counter { get; set; }
    private bool CounterIsVisible { get; set; } = true;
}
```

I want to save the `_Counter` instance, so I can see the correct `_Counter.currentCount` that I counted to. I could save it using a method from [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-5.0&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-3.0&pivots=server#client-side-in-the-browser), but I find them all unpractical, because

- the component I am building has much more data than just a single variable
- I need the data only as long as the `CounterContainer` exists and only for visualisation
- It is just too complicated for my use case

I already have the `Counter` reference stored. I just want to view it instead of reinstanceiating it and overwriting the whole thing.

Hope that made it a bit clearer (:

Comment: Did you figured out since then? I have exactly the same task. Component just needs to be there with data loaded after it was already initialized..

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised it compiles, since you've misspelled your component class:

```
[Parameter] public **InnerCopmonent** _InnerComponent { get; set; }
```

Why do you have an @ref to your InnerComponent at all?  What does InnerComponent do, and why do you want to reference it?  Can you share that component's code?

Comment: Hi @Bennyboy1973, thanks for the response :)
I did not paste any real code so I guess this exact example (now edited) wouldn't compile.

Comment: I added the `@ref` even though it is not 100% relevant to the question, because I need it in my code and I noticed that `@key` and `@ref` sometimes interact weirdly. I feel like it doesn't add much noise, but someone experienced could notice if there is a problem with using both.

Comment: The component is just too long to paste in this question, but I just edited in an extra example. Hope it makes my question somewhat clearer :)

Answer (score 1):

- best option: separate View and Data. The state you want to preserve should not be kept inside the component but in a separate (ViewModel) object.
- short solution: always render the component. Use @isVisible to turn a css-class on/off to hide it.

Comment: I like your first option.  The second one seems kind of anti-Blazor, and it seems to me that its worst sin is that it would work, and the OP might just do that from now on.

Comment: Yeah the firs option is good and I already do have a separate view and data model. It is just that the information that I am trying to preserve belongs in the view model (the `Counter` component) and not really in the data model. 
I hadn't thought on using ccs, but I don't know if it the solution that I am looking for.
Thanks for the suggestions though!

Answer (score 0):

The way I like to do this kind of thing is to create a carrying class which I instantiate in the parent and pass to the child as a `Parameter`.  Since a class is passed by reference, I don't need to worry about events or anything like that.  (I just made up a class for demo to show you can have whatever you want in it)

**CounterData.cs**

```
public class CounterData
    {
        public int counter { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; } = "Counter";
        public List<int> CounterHistory { get; set; } = new List<int>();
    }
```

**CounterContainer.razor**

```
@page "/counter"

<h3>Counter Container</h3>

<button @onclick="()=> ShowCounter=!ShowCounter">Toggle</button>

@if (ShowCounter)
{
    <Counter CarryingInstance="PersistentData" />
}

@code {
    CounterData PersistentData = new CounterData();
    bool ShowCounter = false;
}
```

**Counter.razor**

```
<h3>@CarryingInstance.Title</h3>

<input @bind="CarryingInstance.Title" /><br />
<button @onclick="()=> Increment(1)">Add</button>
<button @onclick="()=>Increment(-1)">Sub</button>
@CarryingInstance.counter <br />


History:

@foreach (var item in CarryingInstance.CounterHistory)
{
    <span>&nbsp; @item</span>
}

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public CounterData CarryingInstance { get; set; }

    void Increment (int amount)
    {
        CarryingInstance.counter += amount;
        CarryingInstance.CounterHistory.Add(CarryingInstance.counter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer!
I do have a class similar to `CounterData`, but the information that I am trying to preserve does not really belong in the `CounterData` object, but rather in the `Counter` component as well (it is just visual data with the same scope as the 'ConterContainer')

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the option of hiding the component with CSS  and the unexpected problems it can cause because components then aren't going through normal life cycle events when they are legitimately rerendered/reinstantiated. So I'm busy updating several components to fix that exact thing. My advice would be to avoid doing that if possible.

Another way, similar to BennyBoys carrying instance method, is you could probably do it is by utilizing dependency injection and registering a type as a scoped or singleton service and having it injected into the component.

You can read here on Chris Sainty's blog about how the different registrations work in blazor and their behaviour and if it'll fit your needs.

https://chrissainty.com/service-lifetimes-in-blazor/

I would double check via official docs that these still behave the same way though just in case but it might be a nice way to do it. I think it depends on what your actual use case is whether it's a good idea to do it like this, but it's another option :)

Comment: Yeah, but I definitely don't want to register this data in a service. It is just too complicated for my use-case :/ Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

What I did for that is use the html style attribute like this:

```
<InnerComponent style="@(IsVisible ? "display:block" : "display:none")"></InnerComponent>
```

When using @if Blazor add/remove the component from the DOM so when it's added back, it follow the initialization life cycle.